# Copy one row's formula to multiple rows in google apps script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script to copy one row's formula and save it other rows so that the formula changes with the cell values. But for some reason, every time I run my function, I get no error but the formulas don't get copied also.

Here is my code,

```
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss_id);
var newSheet = ssNew.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var formula_source = newSheet.getRange(2, 2, 1, 5);
var copy_range = newSheet.getRange(3, 2, 10, 5);
formula_source.copyTo(copy_range);
```

How can I copy one row's formula to several rows on the same sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You should authorize your script in Script Editor before you run function from spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the ranges in your code.

```
var formula_source = newSheet.getRange(2, 2, 1, 5);
var copy_range = newSheet.getRange(3, 2, 10, 5);
```

But not actually doing anything with them.
Something like this might work

```
var formula_source = newSheet.getRange(2, 2, 1, 5).getFormulas();

copy_range.setFormulas(formula_source);
```

Your ranges also don't match, one is larger than the other, so this might  cause issues, without testing the script